# PHP scandir to identify contents of a remote drive

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP to scan a remote server and return the folder/file contents.  This is not a web server, just a remote drive.  I tried the following based on php documentation but no luck.

```
$drive = "//datagrovenm/labdata/";

$files = scandir($drive);

print_r($files);
```

I can map to the drive from the server that I run my PHP on with no problems but can't seem to get scandir to work to catalog it (it works fine on my c: drive).  I also tried the opendir method mentioned in the documentation it did not work either.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You will have to find out the user which PHP runs as and see if that remote drive has granted either the 'PHP user' or 'everyone' read permission

Comment: Also I am pretty sure either way would work but try `$drive = "\\\\datagrovenm\\labdata\\";`

Comment: You should enable error_reporting and see why scandir can't access the folder. Also in windows you should use \ instead of /

Comment: MonkeyZeus, I tried reformatting but still no luck.  I get the following error:

Comment: Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => scandir(): (errno 0): No error [file] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yodaLine\scanDrive.php [line] => 7 ) 1

Comment: I apologize for the confusion on my part.  Taking a shortcut I was running in my browser and it didn't work but when I check on my server while debugging I saw that the results were being sent to my server when I used the format recommended by MonkeyZeus.  Thanks for the input.